# Handling non-block html elements with angle bracket components (webcomponents)

Tags: ember.js, web-component

This question relates specifically to the new Ember angle bracket component syntax, but also in general to Web Components.

I am working on upgrading an Ember application that is not on the later versions of Ember, and I decided that I would use the Ember 1.13 beta so that I can take advantage of the angle brackets components already.

I have a lot of components that built html hierarchies with other elements than `div`, such as a table where every `tbody`/`tr`/`td` is a component (for let's say having a form inside a table for manipulating rows) or a list where every `li` is a component. I was surprised to see that `<my-component>` is actually generated as `<my-component>` in the final html, even with `tagName` property set. Maybe this was unsurprising to every one else, but for me it will be a much bigger change than anything else announced for Ember 2.0. I read a bunch of articles about Web Components and couldn't see any mention of this issue, so maybe it is just a fundamental misunderstanding on my part.

How do you create components (Web/Ember) that are not block level? By restructuring your html to only have block elements as components? By writing a bunch of css to change them to non-block (such as using `display: table-row`) elements?

Comment: Did you find any solution on this? I have a select component that breaks in 1.13 because of this.

Comment: @TimmieSarjanen: Nope, no solution. Zero answers so far in [Ember forums](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-do-you-handle-non-block-html-elements-with-angle-bracket-components/8022), on Slack Ember Community and here.

Comment: I created an issue duo to this and tagName isn't supported yet. Read more here https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11245

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that there is no answer currently. The behaviour of angle bracket components is being worked out and there is an RFC suggesting how they should behave:

https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/angle-bracket-components/active/0000-component-unification.md